# Giving colors to line plot in R

Tags: r, matrix, plot, colors

I have the following matrix (defined as cashflow) that I want to plot in a line plot.

```
     [,1]       [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]   
 [1,] 2498237  3018931.0 3351470 3369931 3361170 
 [2,] 2498237  2996003.7 3238663 3330045 3355259 
 [3,] 2498237  2984259.1 3055009 3290842 3280611 
 [4,] 2498237  2951007.4 3034455 3272052 3271609 
 [5,] 2498237  2854107.7 2927473 3180767 3264394 
 [6,] 2498237  2831014.7 2898604 3066758 3229430 
 [7,] 2498237  2817957.7 2897599 3028093 3171877 
 [8,] 2498237  2802613.5 2897572 2988316 3065650 
 [9,] 2498237  2761771.7 2885572 2985963 3059341 
[10,] 2498237  2753574.5 2841593 2822220 2877972
```

I want to give colors to each row. However, I want rows >= row[6,] to have the same color (ex. red), rows between row[6] and row[3,] to have the same color (ex. blue), and rows =< row[3,] to have the same color (ex. green).

How may I implement this into the r-code below?

```
plot(timeline,casflow[1,], ylim=range(2000000,5000000), type ="l")
for (i in 1:total.simulations){
lines(timeline,cashflow[i,])}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the logic for rownumbers: 1,3,6,..

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your `timeline` vector but here is what you can do, using `matplot` to avoid the loop:

```
matplot(t(cashflow), type="l", col=c(rep("green",3),rep("blue",2), rep("red",nrow(cashflow)-6+1)))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

If you have `nr` numbers numbers of row (`nr <- nrows(cashflow)`) and you want the 10% (let assume nr, the number of simulations, can be divided by 10) first rows in green and the 10% last rows in red, the other rows in blue, you can do:

First, create your vector of colours:

```
vec_col <- c(rep("green", nr*0.1), rep("blue", nr*0.8), rep("red", nr*0.1))
```

Then plot the lines:

```
matplot(t(cashflow), type="l", col=vec_col)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Lets assume I have 10 000 rows of cash flows. All colums are sorted so that the largest numbers in each column are in row nr. 1. The smallest in row nr. 10 000. Now I want to plot the 10 % lowest rows (nr 9000 - 10000) in one color, the 10 % largest rows (nr. 1-1000) in one color and the rest in one color. Do you have another solution then your first suggestion? I want write the percentages into the formula in order to be able to change the number of simulations and still have the top 10 % in one color, the bottom 10 % in one color and the rest in one color. –

Comment: @Andreas, see my edit for a solution. If `nr` cannot be divided by 10, then you can use `round` to make `0.1*nr` an integer (and the same for 0.8*nr)

Answer (score 0):

use if in your loop and a color vector

```
plot(timeline,casflow[1,], ylim=range(2000000,5000000), type ="l")
COL <- c("red","blue","green")
for (i in 1:total.simulations){
if(i <= 3) { z <- 3  }
if(i >= 6) { z <- 1  }
if(i > 3 & i < 6 ) { z <- 3  }
lines(timeline,cashflow[i,], col=COL[z])}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Lets assume I have 10 000 rows of cash flows. All colums are sorted so that the largest numbers in each column are in row nr. 1. The smallest in row nr. 10 000.

Now I want to plot the 10 % lowest rows (nr 9000 - 10000) in one color, the 10 % largest rows (nr. 1-1000) in one color
and the rest in one color.

Do you have another solution then your first suggestion? 
  
I want write the percentages into the formula in order to be able to change the number of simulations and still have the top 10 % in one color, the bottom 10 % in one color and the rest in one color.

Comment: simply change i <= 1000 ; i >= 9000 ; i > 1000 & i < 90000